# “No symbols loaded for the current document” ASP.NET C# Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, pdb-files

What to do now, this time??

I hate VS and this symbolic gibberish that never seem to have same solution (if it once was logic) twice. The screendump below says what it says.

As soon as I F5/Start the web project, the breakpoint going yellow. This ONLY affect the aspx.cs file that being changed. The other aspx.cs files can have breakpoints.

When I do rebuild/build all DLL and PDB files are created just fine. They have same compile time and are in same directory. Module-Windows i VS says the symbols are loaded perfectly. Well, yeah, try bite me!

I can tell, all symbolic is working just fine, until I was about doing changes inside those aspx.cs files (which was some time ago since last time). If I reset back the file, the breakpoint are working. If I try to make changes in another file, the problem appears there.

It simply appears like that the symbolic file generator don't understand changes maded in aspx.cs files..

[image: Web Project Settings (build tab, release mode and debug mode)]

Comment: Usually, I do a "Rebuild All", too when I have such a situation.

Comment: I know, which works most of time. Also there can be conflicts with x64/x86 and switching between release/debug.

Comment: I've found a good hint. The WEBAPP have, as seen above, an _dll path. Which are shared with other projects (save space and don't have copies of same files for several projects). Though. this webapp are **still output/copy files to it's own bin/ directory. Accepting the fact to use standard bin/ fixed the problem this time. Why?** (i've used this maaaany times..). Someone with an idea also of course got a correct answer (i don't like answer myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good hint (see my comment higher in this thread).

The WEBAPP have, as seen above, an _dll path.

This _dll path are there because this project has dll files shared with other projects. This means save space and don't have copies of same files for several projects.

Though, 
This raise problems beause the webapp still are output/copy files to it's own sub bin/ directory. And even worse, not ALL needed dlls, which make error when the running web project (due to missing xxWeb.dll, which copies to _dll bin).

Accepting the fact to use standard bin/ fixed the problem this time. Why? The answer on that will not be in this thread, sorry. Someone with an idea would course make a comment here. In general, this isn't a drawback because the webb project binaries **should** be at the end of reference tree..

Answer (score 0):

Have you got compilation debug="true" set in web.config?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens if you have changed the starting url in the *Web -> Start Action -> Start URL* to a different location. It could also be something in the *Web -> Servers* pane where something is set other as expected.

Also make sure the website in IIS (if you have configured IIS) is located to the right directory (where your project builds the output), otherwise it can't start debugging either.

Comment: Thank's. VS built in webdev. I think i found out a part of the problem (which also is may be a part of a other problem, which more are confusing). The Web Application is copying some dll to each own Bin directory. Even if all settings is to the ../../_dll path.

Comment: And i THINK, above question is a secondary effect of that! Because the file that was runned in webdev was taken from that location (with an older PDB), not the location that are defined in the settings (see screendump).

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Command Prompt 
and Run devenv /resetsettings

[image]

[image: Step 2]